# Variables not making it from one JSP to the other when using HttpSession

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am having trouble retrieving any type of parameter from one jsp page to the other using `doPost`, and a form where my method is `post`. Note below is a minimal example.

First, I have two pages:

Here is `search.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>search</title>
  <body>
    <form name="search" method="post" action="search_results.jsp">
    <p>
        <input type="text" class="inputTitle" id="inputTitle" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.inputTitle)}">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my `search_results.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>search results</title>
  <body>
    <p>Title: ${movie.title}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I have a class called `SearchServlet.java`:

```
@WebServlet("/search")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override 
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp").forward(request,response);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String title = request.getParameter("inputTitle");
    String searchTitle;
    try {
    if(title != null && !title.isEmpty()) {
        searchTitle = "hello";
    } else {
        searchTitle = "world";
    }
    session.setAttribute("movie.title", searchTitle);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("search_results.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch(ServletException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }  
}
```

No matter what I enter the result (movie.title) always ends up being empty and so I get `world` on `search_results.jsp`. Why is my parameter not being passed to `search_results.jsp`?

Comment: You might want to alert/print "${fn:escapeXml(param.inputTitle)}" to see what does it actually gives.

Comment: @Roshith When I use console.log("${fn:escapeXml(param.inputTitle)}") and put "hello" in the title, I get a blank string from  console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not happen if you bypass the servlet

Look at your form action

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="search_results.jsp">
```

You are sending the post request directly to the `search_results.jsp`: you should send it to the servlet instead (mapped @ /search)

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="search">
```

Then from the servlet you should forward the request to the `search_result.jsp`, which you actually did.

In addition to that when you call request.getParameter you have to keep in mind that what counts is the name of the input field, not the id. You should change the `id` attribute to `name`

```
<input type="text" class="inputTitle" name="inputTitle" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.inputTitle)}">
```

Lastly, hopefully :) the '.' (dot) might cause issues:

```
session.setAttribute("movie.title", searchTitle);
```

When you retrieve the attribute the dot notation indicates that you are accessing a field in a object called movie

```
<p>Title: ${movie.title}</p>  <!-- you are accessing the title property of a movie object !-->
```

but you do not have that...you have a movietitle, a String presumably. Change the attribute name to something like movietitle without the dot and retrieve it in the jsp the same way. the above lines will become:

```
session.setAttribute("movietitle", searchTitle);

<p>Title: ${movietitle}</p>
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm.. this works in a sense? For whatever reason, the value getting passed in is still null though. So no string is being passed into my servlet, or at least being forwarded to the search_results page.

Comment: request.getParameter relies on the name attribute not the id

Comment: After changing the name to the attribute (inputTitle), I still end up with null being passed in somehow. What is even weirder is using the apache commons String Util library, and checking to see `if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(title)) { searchTitle = "hello"; } else { searchTitle = "world"; }` throws a null pointer exception

Comment: Try getting rid of the value attribute in the input tag (the one you set to param.inputTitle). I think that the parameter will be captured when you send the request over to the servlet

Comment: never mind I believe I found another error: I'll edit my response

Comment: @Alex glad we made it!!

Comment: Thank you so much! You've definitely cleared a lot of this up for me :D